# cast access text to numeric

Tags: ms-access, casting, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm working in access 2007.
I have a couples of tables that I've imported from Excel in the link mode, so access makes a copy of them and I can use them just in read mode. Now I'm in a trouble with a cast. The primary key is text in the first table and integer in the other one. I want to make the first one like a numeric field.

I assume the left table like "Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni" and as the right table "PC_CarelHQ_modificato". I have to do 3 queries, one with a inner join because there must be a (1,1) relation beetween the two tables. A right join to check what there is in the left table that there is also in the right one. Finally I have to do a left join to find what in the right table is also in the left one.

**How can I cast a String to an Integer in order to apply a LIKE comparison?**

Comment: `CInt(stringId)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Now It looks like It is working. How may I check that everything is fine with what I've done? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you get the expected result, that is a way of checking, isn't it? You could also do `CBool(CInt(stringId) = intId)` which will return true if it works as intended.

Comment: Thank you! If I get anything, It doesn't mean there are no logical mistakes. I'm going to try that one. Ok, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE operator is not really the best to use, specially wit a Text field. I would suggest you two alternatives.

**FIRST** : Create a New column in the table with the Number type and then update it with the Numeric value of the Text field, change the PK to the new field and then delete the old field. (most ideal).

**SECOND** : Create a Query that will JOIN the two tables. This is a better alternative to the LIKE operator. Something like;

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.someOtherField
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON CLng(table1.ID) = table2.ID_FK;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to say that the question at the end of the post was introduced by another user that checked what I posted!

Comment: either way the above comment/answer still applies to your scenario.

Comment: Please read the next comment before to get this one. I have tried the second alternative that you give me.  

This query can be executed and It opens a window where Access asks me to insert a value for Numero Inventario. Then, whatever I insert, Access gives me a mistake about that there should be a mistake in the query or It is too much complex, and It asks me to make It simpler. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is actually the query adopted to the tables I actually have got.
SELECT Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario], PC_CarelHQ_modificato
FROM Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni INNER JOIN PC_CarelHQ_modificato 
ON CLng(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario]) =PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv]; Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working in read only mode on the two tables Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni and PC_CarelHQ_modificato, because my boss asks me to work in a link way in these tablese which came from 2 different excel files. So I cannot use your first solution. Thank you!

Comment: So I cannot use your first solution because I'm not allowed to modify anything.

Comment: There are new details about what I have to do in the question! Thank you so much!